# chrome extensions, message passing between popup.html and background.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message

I have a strange problem with my chrome extension.
I want my popup page to be filled with database stuff. So in the background.html I created the connection to the DB. 
The DB answers should be displayed in the popup, so I decided to use chrome.extension.sendRequest method. (hope this is a good idea for its architecture?)

This is the setup:

`POPUP.js`:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
  alert("out"); console.log(response);

  if(response == null){
    alert("No response. :( and the error was "+chrome.extension.lastError.message);
  }
});
```

`Background.html`:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  alert("inside");
  sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

What happens:
my `alert("inside")` fires, so I know the communication was ok from popup to background.
But now there will be no answer!

Also interesting:
when running the same in developer tools mode(check popup) everything works fine!

Comment: I'm seeing the 'out' alert but for some reason it automatically closes in fraction of a second.

Comment: I think you can use 'getBackgroundPage()' directly from the popup page..No need for asynchronous communication..